# Can I create a floating box on Emacs?

Tags: emacs

My concrete case is that I want to do something like this:

[image: http://www.chris-granger.com/images/lightable/inline-docs.png]

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at [popup.el](https://github.com/auto-complete/popup-el) and [pos-tip.el](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/PosTip).  What they implement is tool tip, not floating box, but it would be enough if you want to just show some info around the cursor.  Even if tool tip is not enough, looking at the implementation and playing around with it could give you some idea about what you can do in Emacs.  popup.el uses overlay as @d11wtq suggested.  pos-tip.el uses X-based functions such as `x-show-tip`.

Also [yascroll.el](https://github.com/m2ym/yascroll-el) is a good example of how to use overlay to put things in the right portion of the window (which is hard!).

Comment: +1 for popup.el; it's a [fairly] painless way to get nice looking tips or completion menus; however syntax highlighting (faces) inside the tip will require you to mod some stuff here and there and possibly encounter strange cases of conflicting faces

Answer (score 5):

You can use overlays. Create an overlay with `make-overlay`:

```
(make-overlay (point) (point))
```

Then put some text in it with `overlay-put`.

```
(overlay-put the-ol 'before-string "Tooltip message")
```

In order to right-align the text in that way, you need to `propertize` the whitespace before the string to set the `display` property with `:align-to`, accounting for the space the tooltip itself will take.

```
(concat (propertize " "
                    'display `(space :align-to (- right ,(length tooltip))))
        tooltip)
```